# How can I use a list, that is defined outside of a buttonclick, inside the button click?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a cinema seat booking system with c# as part of a school project. I'm building it all with GUI.

```
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<List<int>> cinema = new List<List<int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            List<int> rowList = new List<int>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
            {
                rowList.Add(0); // 0 means that the seat is empty
            }
            cinema.Add(rowList);
        }

    }
```

As seen in the code above, I have made the rows and the seats in the cinema using 2 lists and some for loops. There's 10 rows with 15 seats each. I have put this code where the form loads because I didn't know where else to put it since I'm somewhat new to GUI.

```
    private void bookBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chooseMovie.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {

            int row = chooseRow.SelectedIndex;
            int seat = chooseSeat.SelectedIndex;

            if (cinema[row][seat] != 0)
            {
                printArea.Text += "Seat is taken";
            }
            else if (cinema[row][seat] == 0)
            {
                // Booking the seat
                cinema[row][seat] = 1;

                if (cinema[row][seat] == 1)
                {
                    printArea.Text += "The seat on row " + (row+ 1) + " seat " + (seat+ 1) + " has been booked.";
                }

            } else
            {
                printArea.Text += "error";
            }
        }
    }
```

The code above is the button click itself. But since the cinema list is not inside the same button click, it shows an error as following: "The name 'cinema' does not exsist in the current context".

My question is; what do I have to do to be able to use the lists inside of the button click?

I tried placing the lists and loops inside a new public class, but that didn't work. Since the Form1_Load is set as public I thought this would work. I can't put the lists inside the button click because I don't want new lists every time the button is clicked.

Comment: You need to look into fields and properties of a class.

Comment: `cinema` is a local variable which is in scope for only `Form1_Load` method. You can make it a property or field of the holding class.

Comment: @GuruStron How do I make it not local? I'm not familiar with what the holding class means.

Comment: @Marcus "holding class" means the class which has the methods declared.

Comment: @Marcus move the code that says ```List<List<int>> cinema = new List<List<int>>();``` to be outside of the ```Form1_Load``` function, for example, just above it. Then it becomes a field on the holding class.

Comment: @JohanvanTonder Thank you so much, this fixed all the problems I had with the program!